# Regexp issue in java

Tags: java, regex

All,

Below is the pseudo code for pattern matching,

When am passing both regexp and input as String literals, am getting valid response

```
matchPattern(Pattern.compile("^IN\\|Web\\|Track\\|Shop\\|","IN|Coy|")

Pattern ^IN\|Web\|Track\|Shop\| ,matched false  for IN|Coy
```

but when the same regexp is passed derived from bean , i get incorrect response

```
Bean.PatternValue ="^IN\\|Web\\|Track\\|Shop\\|";

matchPattern(Pattern.compile(Bean.PatternValue ),"IN|Coy|")

Pattern ^IN\\|Web\\|Track\\|Shop\\| ,matched true  for IN|Coy|
```

And matchPattern does the following.

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
if (matcher.find()) {
    matched= true;
}
```

Comment: In the second scenario asm seeing \\ for the pattern whereas in the first one, it removes the escape sequence

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Do you do anything else besides making code slower and titles worse?

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: Unless you were seeing something I'm not, there are no tags in the original title. It clearly describes the problem... unlike what you've proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\\` in string literals encodes a single `\`, which the regex parser is interpreting as an escape for the following `|`. So, `"^IN\\|Web\\|Track\\|Shop\\|"` will match the **literal** text `IN|Web|Track|Shop|` at the start of the input. I'm not sure if that's what you want, but it doesn't sound likely.

If you want to match a literal `\`, that must be escaped as `\\` in the pattern, which must be escaped again when writing it in a String literal. I.e.,

```
"^(?:IN\\\\|Web\\\\|Track\\\\|Shop\\\\)"
```

Or:

```
"^(?:IN|Web|Track|Shop)\\\\"
```

I also added grouping brackets around the words there, so that the `^` applies to all of them and not just `IN`... and removed the trailing `|` to prevent it from simply matching anything at all.. again I'm not really sure if that's what you want, but it's another possible problem.

Comment: No Boann , my issue is am passing the same pattern to singlemethod , one as a string literal and another from the bean value but again same pattern,  When you look at the output the pattern is different. In both the cases, its the same pattern literal , even bean property is string type

Comment: @oxygenan It's *not* the same pattern. Look at the lines in the question, where it says: `Pattern ^IN\|Web\|Track\|Shop\| ,matched false` and `Pattern ^IN\\|Web\\|Track\\|Shop\\| ,matched true`. I don't know which one of those is the one you want, but they're not the same.

Comment: maybe i didnt put it properly,sorry about that.. the problem is am passing same pattern string to the same method in 2 ways but in the output , the pattern is printed as is when am passing it from the bean.. I had printed the pattern string for both the cases before invoking the method and they are identical..And the crux of the issue is they are not ending up as same pattern

Comment: Or to put it more simply, what should be the value in the bean for the pattern to hold like the string literal pattern

Comment: @oxygenan What does it say if you do: `String p = "^IN\\|Web\\|Track\\|Shop\\|"; System.out.println(p); System.out.println(Bean.PatternValue); System.out.println(Bean.PatternValue.equals(p));` ?

Comment: Thanks Boann!!! the reg exp patterns were retrieved from backend and it already have the literals...with \\  which is what java string object would create for a single \ once the backend reg ex was changed to \ , it worked... Your .equals suggestion was the key..to figure the reason..